# Why does Joomla or #__session table delete my "session expired" entry without me refreshing the html page?

Tags: php, mysql, session, joomla, joomla1.5

I have 3 Joomla 1.5 applications that use the same MySQL database. This means they all use the same #__session table.

Currently I am having some troubles with "session lifetime", it seems to be set to 15 minutes. I know that from "Global Configuration" you can set it to a longer time and I have set it to 90 minutes. From that point on sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not.

I tried to investigate why this happens (I still do not know why), and so I've encountered another thing that I do not understand and this is what my question is about.

When I log in the administrator part of the application, I see the new session entry in the #__session table. This entry has a time stamp to it. I change that time stamp so that the user session is expired (logged_in_timestamp - 90 minutes = logged_out_timestamp). I wait about 3-4 minutes more and refresh NOT THE HTML PAGE, but the data in the #__session table and I see that my entry with my current username got deleted.

**Why does Joomla or #__session table delete my "session expired" entry without me refreshing the html page?**

I think if I find the answer to this I could know why sometimes it takes 90 minutes to logout and why sometimes it takes 15 minutes to logout.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to refresh the page yourself - any visit to the Joomla website will trigger a small script which deletes old sessions.

Comment: Could you tell me where is this script? Where I can find it? I want to see the code.

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with $app->logout() bringing me to a login page, and then deleting my session, so the login attempt will fail. I need to find this script, or find a way to logout after the session has been cleared.

Comment: It's in the `libraries/joomla/session/storage/database.php` - the functions are `destroy` and `gc` - from this post ( http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-completely-disable-session-activity-for-visitors-on-joomla-websites - the post mentions all the places that directly interact with the `#__session` table on a Joomla website)